# React Hooks is somehow using previous state to set new state

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm making a chess training website where a teacher (referred to as 'admin' in my code) and several students will be connected together via sockets (used Socket.io). The teacher can put pieces on board and clear the board to teach students. But the clearing of board is not working properly.

I'm using sockets to send information that the board was cleared by the teacher, and react does clear the board at first, but when another piece is put on the board by the teacher, react updates the state using previous state. I know this might sound confusing so I've attached a video file.

https://youtu.be/yLlJMCDjfpw

As you can see the previous pieces are still appearing on the student's board even thought the board should've been resetted to an 8x8 matrix with all zeros.

I have provided my code below, and all the code I've provided is in the same file.
I've omitted the returned JSX and some other small functions as they were too long and I don't think was necessary

```
const initialEmptyBoard = getEmptyBoard(); // getEmptyBoard() retuns an 8x8 matrix of all zeros

const ChessWorkshopBoard = () => {
    const { socket } = useSelector(state => state.socket);
    const { userLoginInfo } = useSelector(state => state.userLoginInfo);

    const [board, setBoard] = useState(initialEmptyBoard);
    const [gameStarted, setGameStarted] = useState(false);

    const [gameOver, setGameOver] = useState({
        gameOver: false,
        winnerName: null,
        winnerColor: null
    });

    const [showPawnPromotionDialog, setShowPawnPromotionDialog] = useState({
        show: false,
        cellsClicked: null,
        pawnColor: null
    });

    const windowSize = useWindowSize();

    const chessPieceColor = useRef("white");
    const whiteKingPos = useRef([]);
    const blackKingPos = useRef([]);

    const [arrows, setArrows] = useState([]);
    const [arrowColor, setArrowColor] = useState("#d63031");
    const arrowPos = useRef({ rows: [], cols: [] });
    const [redCrosses, setRedCrosses] = useState([]);

    const game = useRef();

    const handlePawnPromotion = pieceName => {
        let { cellsClicked } = showPawnPromotionDialog;
        let tempBoard = board.map(b => b);

        // the pawn has been moved at this point
        game.current.promotePawn(tempBoard, pieceName, cellsClicked);

        setBoard(tempBoard);

        setShowPawnPromotionDialog({ show: false, cellsClicked: null, pawnColor: null });
    };

    const putPieceOnBoard = (pieceName, pieceColor, row, col) => {
        console.log("board = ", board);

        let tempBoard = board.map(b => b);

        console.log("putPieceOnBoard = ", pieceName, pieceColor, row, col);

        switch (pieceName) {
            case "redcross":
                setRedCrosses(r => [
                    ...r,
                    {
                        top: row * 70,
                        left: col * 70
                    }
                ]);
                break;

            case "queen":
                tempBoard[row][col] = new Queen(pieceColor, row, col);
                break;

            case "rook":
                tempBoard[row][col] = new Rook(pieceColor, row, col);
                break;

            case "bishop":
                tempBoard[row][col] = new Bishop(pieceColor, row, col);
                break;

            case "knight":
                tempBoard[row][col] = new Knight(pieceColor, row, col);
                break;

            case "king":
                tempBoard[row][col] = new King(pieceColor, row, col);

                if (pieceColor === "white") whiteKingPos.current = [row, col];
                else blackKingPos.current = [row, col];

                break;

            case "pawn":
                tempBoard[row][col] = new Pawn(pieceColor, row, col);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (userLoginInfo?.isAdmin) {
            socket.emit("adminPutPieceOnBoard", { pieceName, pieceColor, row, col });
        }

        setBoard(b => tempBoard);
    };

    const dragHasEnded = e => {
        const ele = document.getElementById("checkersBoard");
        const eleRect = ele.getBoundingClientRect();
        const targetRect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();

        // Calculate the top and left positions
        const top = Math.abs(eleRect.top - targetRect.top);
        const left = Math.abs(eleRect.left - targetRect.left);

        const row = Math.floor(top / 65);
        const col = Math.floor(left / 65);

        if (row < 0 || row > 7 || col < 0 || col > 7) return;

        if (e.target.tagName === "DIV") return;

        let imgSrc = e.target.getAttribute("src");
        let pieceColor, pieceName;

        const possibleNames = imgSrc.slice(imgSrc.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        pieceColor = possibleNames.slice(0, 5);
        pieceName = possibleNames.split(".")[0].toLowerCase().trim();

        if (pieceName !== "redcross") {
            pieceName = pieceName.slice(5);
        }

        putPieceOnBoard(pieceName, pieceColor, row, col);
    };

    const clearArrowsAndCrosses = useCallback(() => {
        if (userLoginInfo?.isAdmin) {
            socket.emit("adminClearedArrowsAndCrosses");
        }

        setArrows([]);
        setRedCrosses([]);
    }, [socket, userLoginInfo]);

    // this is the function is question
    // it successfully clears the board for the teacher but doesn't do 
    // so for the students

    const resetBoard = () => {
        if (userLoginInfo?.isAdmin) {
            socket.emit("boardResetted");
        }

        console.log("board is being reset");

        game.current = null;
        chessPieceColor.current = "white";
        
        /* 
        I've tried doing setBoard(() => getEmptyBoard()) and setBoard(getEmptyBoard()) but 
        they were not even clearing the board for the teacher
        */

        setBoard([
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        ]);
        setGameOver({
            gameOver: false,
            winnerName: null,
            winnerColor: null
        });
        setGameStarted(false);
        clearArrowsAndCrosses();
    };


    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("pieceWasPutOnBoard", ({ pieceName, pieceColor, row, col }) => {
            putPieceOnBoard(pieceName, pieceColor, row, col);
        });
    }, [socket]);


    useEffect(() => {

        socket.on("boardHasBeenResetted", () => { 
        // this is sent by the server after socket event "" is fired from this file
            resetBoard();
        });
    }, [socket]);




};

export default ChessWorkshopBoard;
```

I've checked the server and it seems like the socket event is getting through to the server and it is firing. I'll put the server code here just in case.

```
   
    // the send the piece, it's color and the coordinates of where the piece was 
    // put on the board 
 
    socket.on("adminPutPieceOnBoard", ({ pieceName, pieceColor, row, col }) => {
        console.log("\n\npieceWasPutOnBoard", { pieceName, pieceColor, row, col });

        socket
            .to(socket.room)
            .emit("pieceWasPutOnBoard", { pieceName, pieceColor, row, col });
    });

    // reset the board. i.e clear the board of all pieces and arrows and set it
    // to its default value of an 8x8 matrix of all zeros

    socket.on("boardResetted", () => {
        // I checked the console and this function is firing.
        // so I don't think the problem is here, but in the client-code

        socket.to(socket.room).emit("boardHasBeenResetted");
        console.log("\n\nboardResetted\n\n");
    });
```

Comment: could you put together a jsfiddle

Comment: I don't know how to do that. And how would sockets work in a sandbox?